# using session within template in flask jinja2 application?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I made a small test project. See https://github.com/rkiddy/flask_template for setup. I expect to see "maybe" on the page upon first access. Then I expect to be able to save to the session and use the value as shown. I think the documentation I have seen says this is how it works.

For example, see the index.html described in this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-flask-session-in-python-flask/

Here is my project. This is all of it. Everything.

```
$ find * | grep -v __
app.py
pages
pages/app_main.html
requirements.txt
```

and

```
$ cat app.py 

import sys

from dotenv import dotenv_values
from flask import Flask, session
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

cfg = dotenv_values(".env")

sys.path.append(f"{cfg['APP_HOME']}")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.secret_key = b'aae14431-9269-4322-958e-7dbb4474bf7a'
application = app 
env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('app', 'pages'))


@app.route("/")
def app_main():
    main = env.get_template('app_main.html')
    session['yesOrNo'] = 'maybe'
    context = dict()
    print(f"the yesOrNo value is {session.get('yesOrNo')}")
return main.render(**context)


@app.route("/setyes")
def app_yes():
    main = env.get_template('app_main.html')
    session['yesOrNo'] = 'yes'
    context = dict()
    return main.render(**context)

@app.route("/setno")
def app_no():
    main = env.get_template('app_main.html')
    session['yesOrNo'] = 'no'
    context = dict()
    return main.render(**context)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and

```
$ cat pages/app_main.html 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>{{ session.yesOrNo }}</p>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Any idea why the {{ session.yesOrNo }} does not work?

I am getting:

```
 * Detected change in '/home/ray/Projects/test_session/app.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 978-769-374
the yesOrNo value is maybe
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Apr/2023 14:27:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ray/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ray/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/ray/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ray/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ray/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ray/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/home/ray/Projects/test_session/app.py", line 25, in app_main
    return main.render(**context)
  File "/home/ray/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1301, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/home/ray/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "/home/ray/Projects/test_session/pages/app_main.html", line 8, in top-level template code
    <p>{{ session.yesOrNo }}</p>
  File "/home/ray/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 485, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'session' is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the built in Flask function to render your template (`flask.render_template()`) you're creating a Jinja2 environment yourself and rendering the template without any of the Flask helpers. This means that you won't have any Flask specific context when rendering, which is why `session` is undefined.

Instead of rendering with a Jinja2 environment directly, you should use `flask.render_template("app_main.html")`, and then `session` will be available in the template rendering context for you to use.

An extra thing to note is that as you're using a non-standard directory for your templates, `pages`, you will need to specify that when instantiating your Flask app with `template_folder`. See [the Flask docs for this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Flask).

As it looks like you're new to Flask, I think it would be useful to read through a Flask templating tutorial. [Digital Ocean have one here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-templates-in-a-flask-application) that looks like it might be a good place to start.